# How can I bring my website up in the google search result?

Tags: seo, google, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I have developed my website few months ago and I added meta tags and described everything as much as I could but my site is still not on the top when I search kashif ejaz on google. Please help !

Comment: It does when I search (I'm in the UK). Do you want to try again?

Comment: I tried several time but it is not at the top here. It is good to hear that you see it at the top :)